# Hosted network dying after some time

Tags: networking, windows-10

So thanks to my landlord who set a damn MAC filter on the router out of paranoia and is unable/unwilling to come over and add new devices any other day than rent collection day, I had to outsmart him.

My laptop can redistribute a wireless network using the standard Windows hostednetwork feature. First I used Virtual Router Manager to create a hotspot, which worked fine for about four hours. After that I was getting "no internet access" on all connected devices.

I've played around and tried various other options (Virtual Router Plus, netsh commands, etc.), to no avail. After some usage the created virtual network simply does not transfer any data.

Has anyone had this issue before? I'm thinking of a cache overload as it seems to be affected by the amount of transmitted data and not the time the network is up (and the only way to get it working is to either completely restart the network stack via airplane mode, or to reboot the computer).

Answer (score 0):

Note:  It is possible your landlord could have a system with countermeasures that block this.

I am recommending a new device because otherwise the laptop with a high power draw has to stay on versus a 10w(approx) device.

1. write down your MAC
2. buy a linksys/netgear/ or etc
3. reprogram it with your computers MAC
    usually http://192.168.1.1 or http://192.168.1.100
4. connect all your device to it.

All traffic now looks like it is coming from your laptop.

Comment: Fortunately my landlord is not that much of an IT geek. He just knows how to enable the basic MAC filtering (and hidden SSID) on the router. Also I only need this when I'm at home, and at that time, my laptop is usually on, so it's not a big issue.

Comment: @fonix232  Then my idea should work fine.  Cloning the MAC to a netgear or whatever that has many ports and/or wifi.

Comment: Yeah. Except I can't connect through LAN (landlord disabled all LAN ports except WAN).